# Get only returns json with only first 146 characters of result

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an asp net core 2.1 web api running against ef core 2 pointed at a database on localdb.

Here are my poco classes:

```
public class Organization
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public IList<Production> Productions { get; set; }
        public IList<OrganizationPerson> OrganizationPeople { get; set; }
    }

public class Production
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
        public Organization Organization { get; set; }
    }


 public class OrganizationPerson
    {
        public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
        public int PersonId { get; set; }

        public Organization Organization { get; set; }
        public Person Person { get; set; }
    }
```

My context:

```
public class AuditioneerContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Production> Productions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrganizationPerson> OrganizationPersons { get; set; }
     }
```

Here's the method from my web api:

```
[HttpGet]      
public IEnumerable<Organization> Get()
{
    var result =
        context.Organizations
           .Include(o=>o.Productions)
           .ToList();
    return result;
}
```

When I call this method, no error is thrown, and I get the first 146 characters of the json result, but not the rest.

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Ridgefield Theater Barn","productions":[{"id":1,"name":"Godspell","description":"Godspell by Stephen Schwartz","organizationId":1
```

I don't understand why only part of the result is returned.

Is there a piece of code missing from my Startup that would cause this?

If I put a breakpoint in the Get method, the result variable contains the correct data

Comment: Did you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655436/json-response-gets-truncated-in-web-api-using-asp-net-core?

Comment: Searched but didnt find that - just tried it and it worked, Thanks!

Comment: The problem is caused by the circular reference between Organization and OrganizationPerson. Glad to see you already have a solution :-)

Comment: Also: now it's a good time to learn that EF entities shouldn't be returned "as is". You should create Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) and return them instead

Comment: Thanks Camilo, Currently I'm in a prototyping phase, after which I will incorporate DTOs